What does a glass of extracted teeth symbolize in the horror movie, Possum?
In the horror movie, Possum, Philips finally goes into the locked room and discovers it is a burned room, where there is a glass of extracted teeth.
What does this glass of extracted teeth symbolize in the context of this movie?
